# How to change width of Radgrid of telerik using jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid

I have stuck in one issue where grid headers are not moving with horizontal scroll.

I found that the issue comes up when we have large amount of data and it removes the width attribute or css from grid div

Please let me know how to change attribute of radgrid using jquery

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading to the latest version, there have been some fixes about fromzen columns and headers and scrolling.

On jQuery - just inspect the HTML and find the class of the element you want to modify. Here are two examples:

the main wrapper div:

```
$(".RadGrid").width("your-width");
```

the master table view:

```
$(".rgMasterTable").width("your-width");
```

where you may want to add more specificity to the selectors so they don't target all grids or the first grid.